# Mask and aggregate bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm trying to efficiently execute the following task:

```
INPUT VALUE: 01101011
MASK:        00110010
MASK RESULT: --10--1-
AGGREGATED:  00000101
```

I hope this examples explains clearly what I'm trying to achieve. What's the best way to do this in a non-naive way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This operation is called [`compress_right`](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e) or just `compress`, and it is moderately terrible to implement without hardware support. The non-naive code from Hacker's Delight "7–4 Compress, or Generalized Extract" to implement this function is

```c
unsigned compress(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
    unsigned mk, mp, mv, t;
    int i;
    x = x & m;    // Clear irrelevant bits.
    mk = ~m << 1; // We will count 0's to right.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mp = mk ^ (mk << 1);    // Parallel suffix.
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
        mv = mp & m;     // Bits to move.
        m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i)); // Compress m.
        t = x & mv;
        x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i));   // Compress x.
        mk = mk & ~mp;
    }
    return x;
}
```

BMI2 (implemented in Haswell and later) will have the instruction `pext` for this operation.

---

If the mask is a constant (or not a constant but reused multiple times), a relatively obvious optimization is pre-calculating the 5 values that `mv` takes during the loop. The calculation of `mv` does not depend on `x`, so that can be calculated independantly, like this (the same algorithm as above really)

```c
mk = ~m << 1;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mp = mk ^ (mk << 1);
    mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
    mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
    mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
    mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
    mv = mp & m;
    mask[i] = mv;
    m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i));
    mk = mk & ~mp;
}
```

Still looks complicated, but everything here is a constant, so it can be pre-computed (if the compiler can't do it, then *you* can, simply by running it and then pasting the result into the code). The "real part" of the code, the code that actually has to run at runtime is this:

```c
x = x & m;
t = x & mask[0];
x = x ^ t | (t >> 1);
t = x & mask[1];
x = x ^ t | (t >> 2);
t = x & mask[2];
x = x ^ t | (t >> 4);
t = x & mask[3];
x = x ^ t | (t >> 8);
t = x & mask[4];
x = x ^ t | (t >> 16);
```

(this is also in Hacker's Delight, formatted a little differently)

Many cases can be simpler again, for example:

- if `m = 0`, the result is `0`.
- if `m = -1`, the result is `x`.
- if `m = 1`, the result is `x & 1`.
- if `m = ((1 << n) - 1) << k`, the result is `(x >> k) & m`.
- if `m = 0x80000000`, the result is `x >> 31`.
- if `m` is an other power of two, the result is `(x >> numberOfTrailingZeros(m)) & 1`
- if `m` is alternating, the "perfect unshuffle algorithm" can be used.
- if `m` consists of a few "groups", the "bit group moving" algorithm can be used (ie mask a group, shift it into place (or shift first, mask second), OR all shifted groups together, though more sophisticated approaches exist), this is probably the most important case in practice.
- ...

For example, the mask from your question would fall in the "bit group moving" case, with code like this:

```c
return ((x >> 1) & 1) | ((x >> 3) & 6);
```

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa it can be substantially optimized if the mask is a constant (or a loop constant), by the way.

Comment: Yes, in my scenario it would be a constant, but I think this kind of optimisation is automatically done by the compiler. Or is it better to explicitly do it?

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa it might, but I wouldn't count on it, and the code for a constant mask is simpler anyway. I'll edit in the general optimization, but for many masks the code can be *yet simpler again*. Reliably finding the *best* code for *any* given mask is an open problem as far as I know (though many special cases are known).