# Filtering bit strings efficiently

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am looking for a bit manipulation function that takes two bit strings and filters and compacts the first string based on the second, so only the values where the second string are 1 are kept. Eg:

```
01101010 and 11110000 gives 00000110
01101010 and 00001111 gives 00001010
01101010 and 10101000 gives 00000011
```

By using looping, conditionals and working with each bit independently this is easy to implement, **but I'm looking for a faster method using bit manipulation tricks if one exists, not using conditionals and loops**. It does not have to work for input longer than 32 bits. Therefore a solution would have a signature like: uint32_t filter(uint32_t in, uint32_t mask)

In C it would look something like this with arrays and a loop:

```
void filter(bool in[], bool mask[], bool out[], int size) {
    int output_index = 0;
    for (int input_index = 0; input_index < size; ++input_index) {
        if (mask[input_index]) {
            out[output_index++] = in[input_index];
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a bunch examples of the types of solutions I'm looking for: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: are you sure `01101010 and 11110000 gives 00000110` ?  How did you deduce that ?

Comment: Indexed from the right the first four bits would be skipped, then the next four kept, so 0110 are kept and shifted right.

Comment: in case you index the ouput from right to left the `output_index` should be decremented, not incremented.

Comment: That depends on how you index the bitstring, that assumes indexing with least significant bit first, so the indices into the bitstring are 76543210, see squeamish ossifrage's answer for how that can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to store bit sequences of up to 32 bits, it would be far more efficient to store them as 32-bit unsigned integers. Here's one way of doing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t filter(uint32_t in, uint32_t mask) {
  uint32_t result=0, t, p=1, q=1;
  while (mask) {
    if ( (t = mask & 1) ) {
      if ( (q & in) ) result |= p;
      p <<= 1;
    }
    mask >>= 1;
    q <<= 1;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  /* 01101010 and 11110000 gives 00000110 */
  printf("%04x %04x %04x\n", 0x6a, 0xf0, filter(0x6a,0xf0)); /* Output: 0006 */
  /* 01101010 and 00001111 gives 00001010 */
  printf("%04x %04x %04x\n", 0x6a, 0x0f, filter(0x6a,0x0f)); /* Output: 000a */
  /* 01101010 and 10101000 gives 00000011 */
  printf("%04x %04x %04x\n", 0x6a, 0xa8, filter(0x6a,0xa8)); /* Output: 0003 */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's definitely closer than my naive solution, but I'm hoping there is some smarter solution, through clever bit manipulation: Eg: you can reverse a byte this way `unsigned char b; 
b = (b * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;`

Comment: @BjörnOttosson ... or use a lookup table which could be faster...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to avoid using a loop (other than by unrolling the `while` loop into 32 blocks). However, there may be some way of reducing the number of `if` statements.

Comment: Apparently there is, and there's even an instruction for it on modern Intel processors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751307/mask-and-aggregate-bits :)